# couchdb multi language documents

Tags: couchdb, multilingual

We are considering of using CouchDB for our Systems now. Anybody knows there is a function or framework in CouchDB supports handling different languages of the the same document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your functions fall out of UTF-8, then you probably want to attach them to documents as attachments. That way you can also easily keep multiple translations associated with the same document. For example, have a document that holds the meta data and then an attachment for each language. Keep the attachment names standardized - ie., by en_US or whatever - and you can easily check to see if you have the given translation.

Comment: Sam, yes this fits the needs, should work with attachments and documents , I simply missed the idea of META data documents linked to the actual content documents.

Comment: As a side note, I think that's one of the most confusing things for people when they start to look at CouchDB: it describes itself as a document based database, but it's made to store more than just documents. Ie., you can store users, transactions, shopping carts, logs, coordinates, and really anything else. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Sam, just Looping After sequences for 'Dokuments' now ;)

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB documents are Unicode text using UTF-8, so all languages supported by Unicode are supported.

Answer (score 0):

wikipedia helps understand couchdb's concept of document :
from their CouchDB page you can , you then find [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) .